# sizeof() returning different values even when the two variables contain the same string

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, sizeof

I am getting different values on sizeof for the same string value.

when I run the below code in C:

```
char str[] = "November";
char *s = "November";
printf(" str[] = %ld\n",sizeof(str));
printf(" *s = %ld\n",sizeof(s));
```

expected output:

```
str[] = 9
*s = 9
```

Actual output:

```
str[] = 9
*s = 8
```

What is going on actually?

Comment: Size of array vs size of a pointer.

Comment: Read about the [sizeof operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)

Answer (score 4):

- `sizeof(str)` is the size of `char` array `str` which contains 9 elements (including the null terminator) and therefore 9 bytes.
- `sizeof(s)` is the size of pointer to `char` which is 8 bytes on your system

Comment: is there any way to get the size of the string from *s?

Comment: No. `*s` is now the first character of the string, so `sizeof(*s)` will be 1.

Answer (score 3):

sizeof() is not strlen()

the size of a pointer is not the size of the pointed element